# Migration from myfaces 1.1 to 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, myfaces

I'm trying to upgrade our web application from myfaces 1.1 to 1.2. I hoped it is easier than migration directly to the newest 2.x version. However, I'm getting such an error, when I'm trying to start the application:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:106)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:137)
at evo.ui.jsf.EvoFacesServlet.init(EvoFacesServlet.java:56)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

In the application log such an exception can be observed:

```
2012-09-26 15:44:00|main|ERROR|org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer|An error occured while initializing MyFaces: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:61)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:96)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<description>My app</description>
<display-name>My app</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
    <param-value>evo.ui.jsf.EvoResourceResolver</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>    

<!-- AJAX4JSF -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>evo.ajaxlink.level</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceparser</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>UploadMultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        evo.ui.jsf.filters.UploadMultipartFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>configDatabaseSessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxFileSize</param-name>
        <param-value>20m</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UploadMultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <description>Force encoding to get correct results of sorting
    Global Task List with fields containing non-ASCII characters.
    </description>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>            
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>evo.ui.jsf.EvoFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- XFIRE Webservices -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>xfire</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xfire</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

The <web-app> tag has been updated to version="2.5" from "2.4". I have already tried replacing our delegated servlet (EvoFacesServlet) with original, javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet, without success.

The servlet container is Tomcat 6.

What else should I do to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing container-related jars from the deployment helped: servlet-api.jar, el-api.jar, jsp-api.jar. Not sure which one of them was the source of the problem.

Comment: how did your dependencies look like? Did you also have to upgrade org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk and tiles?

Comment: I don't remember. It was long time ago.